# How to group by one field

Tags: views, database

I have a view which shows the users subscribed to the website. Some users have multiple roles, therefore, on the results, there are some duplicates.

What I want to do is to remove these duplicates, so I've tried to enable the *Aggregation* in the view settings. This action reduced the repeated results, but it haven't erased them. 
By looking at the query the `GROUP BY` is done for every field, but I want to enable for just one field, more specifically like this: `GROUP BY users_name`.

I've tried to achieve it by making a simple module with this function:

```
function alter_users_query_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == 'all_users') {
        $query->add_groupby('users_name');
    }
}
```

Which adds the additional field in the `GROUP BY`, but it doesn't remove the others. 
How can I achieve it? More specifically, how can I unset the other fields and group by just one?

Comment: Does your MySQL instance have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set to false? If not what you're describing won't be possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by following [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79965/how-to-remove-duplicate-from-views-result-page?rq=1) example. Here is the code in my case:

```
function alter_users_query_query_alter($query) {
    if (isset($query->alterMetaData)) {
        if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])) {
            if($query->alterMetaData['view']->name == 'all_users') {
                $fields =& $query->getGroupBy();

                unset($fields['field-you-want-to-remove']);
                $query->groupBy('users_name');
            }
        }
    }
}
```